# How do I make a WebView embedded inside a windows Form display all webpages properly?

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Security.Permissions;
```

I aquire some permission

```
[PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
```

The start of Program class

```
public class Program : Form

{
```

I declare a WebBrowser

```
    private WebBrowser webBrowser;
```

My constructor

```
    public Program()
    {
        InitialiseForm();
    }
```

I innitialise variables and do some layout coding

```
    public void InitialiseForm()
    {
        webBrowser = new WebBrowser();
        Controls.AddRange(new Control[] {webBrowser});
        webBrowser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
        webBrowser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
```

I attempt to navigate to nationalgeographic.com. Other websites like google.com and facebook.com are being displayed properly. However some like throwawaymail.com and nationalgeographic are being displayed with alot of elements apparently missing.

```
        webBrowser.Navigate("http://www.nationalgeographic.com/");

    }

    [STAThread]
```

My main method

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.Run(new Program());
    }
}
```

Comment: The WebBrowser control hosts a particular version of the Internet Explorer rendering engine. Generally this is an old version, which doesn't support all features used on those websites. What have you tried?

Comment: I have tried the above code and I have tried googling for a solution with no success. And what is with you guys and the downvotes. Gosh. Is it too hard to just ask me some questions.

Comment: Okay Thanks. Was that so hard. But please stop those annoying pointless downvotes. Your making StackOverflow limit the number of questions I can ask per day.

Comment: Maybe you should search for an answer before asking and you won't get downvotes...

Comment: Let me try that solution.....

Comment: Okay, I have studied it and it appears that I am supposed to call the "Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)" method in that code. Now, My question is, what are those "Object sender" and "EventArgs e" parameters for. As in, what exactly am I supposed to pass into that method?

Comment: That's the Load event. It's called for you when the form is loaded.

Comment: Huh! so that method is overridden from the Forms class?

Comment: Use `@username` to notify people of your replies (unless you're responding to the post owner, like I am now).  It doesn't matter where you copy-paste the code from the duplicate. A Form's Load event is not overridden, it is subscribed to. You can do this in the designer, very basic WinForms stuff. Or instead paste the code in your `InitialiseForm()`. Anyway read [ask] and share your research. This is not a forum, and if your question is closed as duplicate, don't continue your question in comments. :)

Comment: Okay. Ill use the @username thingy. Don't close my question as duplicate, that's a really mean thing to do. Thanks for the tip. Now, I'm still kinda confused. I thought putting a method into a method in c# will result to a compile-time error. How can I paste all that code into my "Initialiseform()" method yet that code contains other methods?